dplyr add rows (based on condition) that reproduce values (strings) in remaining cols
I've reviewed many 'do X using dplyr based on condition' SO questions, and I believe only this one comes close to what I'm doing. I've tried but cannot manage to adapt @divibisan's answer there.
My data looks like:
df <- tibble(
  Group_ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
  statusA = c("NEW", "NEW", "OLD","NEW", "OLD","OLD"),
  statusB = c("BONUS", NA, "BONUS", NA, NA,"ROLLBACK"),
  someVar = c("Thanks", "for", "your", "help","!","!"))

When statusB is any non-NA value, I want to 'split' (as it were) that row such that for the Group_ID there exists a distinct row for its statusA and its statusB. When rows are 'split', the row with a non-NA value for statusA should show NA for statusB, and the row with a non-NA value for statusB should show NA for statusA. All remaining variables (i.e., other than statusA and statusB) should appear, per each Group_ID, on each line.
desired_df <- tibble(
  Group_ID = c(1,1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6),
  statusA = c("NEW",NA,"NEW","OLD",NA,"NEW","OLD","OLD",NA),
  statusB = c(NA,"BONUS",NA,NA,"BONUS",NA,NA,NA,"ROLLBACK"),
  someVar = c("Thanks","Thanks", "for", "your","your","help","!","!","!"))

I strongly wish to avoid using a loop. Can this be accomplished using dplyr?

You can try:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df |> 
  reframe(statusA = c(statusA, NA[!is.na(statusB)]),
          statusB = c(NA[!is.na(statusB)], statusB), .by = -c(statusA, statusB)) |> 
  relocate(c(statusA, statusB), .after = Group_ID)


# A tibble: 9 × 4
  Group_ID statusA statusB  someVar
     <dbl> <chr>   <chr>    <chr>  
1        1 NEW     NA       Thanks 
2        1 NA      BONUS    Thanks 
3        2 NEW     NA       for    
4        3 OLD     NA       your   
5        3 NA      BONUS    your   
6        4 NEW     NA       help   
7        5 OLD     NA       !      
8        6 OLD     NA       !      
9        6 NA      ROLLBACK !   


Excellent! Thank you, @lotus--very helpful! relocate() is new to me but looks really useful

Bind the rows together while blanking each of the other values to NA:
df %>% mutate(statusB = NA) %>%
    bind_rows(df %>% filter(!is.na(statusB)) %>% mutate(statusA = NA)) %>%
    arrange(Group_ID)

##  Group_ID statusA  statusB someVar
##1        1     NEW     <NA>  Thanks
##2        1    <NA>    BONUS  Thanks
##3        2     NEW     <NA>     for
##4        3     OLD     <NA>    your
##5        3    <NA>    BONUS    your
##6        4     NEW     <NA>    help
##7        5     OLD     <NA>       !
##8        6     OLD     <NA>       !
##9        6    <NA> ROLLBACK       !

